# filter rows that have either or specific folds

Tags: r

I'm still learning R, I have this [dataset](https://github.com/learnseq/learning/blob/main/dfpilot.csv), it has 5 columns, first column is tracking_id, the next four columns have values of four groups.

I want to filter rows after comparing the last three columns ("CD44hi_CD69low_rep","CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep","CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep")
that are ***8 folds higher or 4 folds lower*** compared to column ("CD44low_rep").

How to achieve this?

Comment: All columns @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We multiply the 'CD44low_rep' column by 8 and 4, then compare it with the columns of interest using `>=` and `<=` respectively, get the rowwise sum of TRUE values with `rowSums`, check if it is equal to 3 (i.e. the number of columns compared), use `&` to return a single logical vector from both comparisons, and use that to subset the rows

```
nm1 <- c("CD44hi_CD69low_rep",  "CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep", 
         "CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep")
i1 <- (rowSums(df1[nm1]  >= (df1$CD44low_rep * 8)) == 3) &
     (rowSums(df1[nm1]  <= (df1$CD44low_rep * 4)) == 3)

df1[i1,]
# A tibble: 798 x 5
#   tracking_id   CD44low_rep CD44hi_CD69low_rep CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep
#   <chr>               <dbl>              <dbl>                      <dbl>                     <dbl>
# 1 1600014C23Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 2 1600019K03Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 3 1700006E09Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 4 1700010M22Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 5 1700011A15Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 6 1700016P04Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 7 1700018G05Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 8 1700019A02Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 9 1700024B18Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
#10 1700024G13Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# … with 788 more rows
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we use the same expression by looping over the columns of interest with `across` (by default, it does the check for `all` columns)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     filter(across(contains('hi'), ~ (. >= (CD44low_rep * 8)) & 
                (. <= (CD44low_rep * 4))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 798 x 5
#   tracking_id   CD44low_rep CD44hi_CD69low_rep CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep
#   <chr>               <dbl>              <dbl>                      <dbl>                     <dbl>
# 1 1600014C23Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 2 1600019K03Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 3 1700006E09Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 4 1700010M22Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 5 1700011A15Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 6 1700016P04Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 7 1700018G05Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 8 1700019A02Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# 9 1700024B18Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
#10 1700024G13Rik           0                  0                          0                         0
# … with 788 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, something missing in the first option, I get this error `Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:35:60: unexpected ']'
34: i1 <- (rowSums(df1[nm1]  >= (df1$CD44low_rep * 8)[col(df1[nm1])]) == 3) &
35:    (rowSums(df1[nm1]  <= (df1$CD44low_rep * 4)[col(df1[nm1]]`
                                                               ^

Comment: @user432797 now, it should work.  I made a change and forgot to change it here

Comment: Thank you so much @akrun, I tried first to filter out from the data frame any value equal or more than 1, I used `df1 %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>%  filter_all(all_vars(. >= 1))`, then I tried your code to filter the condition in the question (8 folds more or 4 less), but I'm getting no output! any suggestion?

Comment: @user432797 Probably in the filtered data, you may not have both conditions met because your new filtered data is 7270 rows as opposed to original data of 23746

Comment: @user432797 if you check for the first condition only, then there is 18 rows `df2 %>% filter(across(contains('hi'), ~ (. >= (CD44low_rep * 8))))` where df2 is the filtered one.  THen, when you combined with the second, you may not have any common case.  May be you need `|` condition instead of `&`

Comment: @user432797 if it is OR condition `df2 %>% filter((across(contains('hi'), ~ (. >= (CD44low_rep * 8))))| (across(contains('hi'), ~ (. <= (CD44low_rep * 4)))))`

Comment: Thank you so much @Akrun, I'm getting the whole 23K lines after the line, I will post a separate question detailing the three conditions together.

Comment: @user432797 I think it is the `|` because you can't have both conditions simultaneously met for the same row.

Comment: @user432797 when you post a quesiton, can you make a small example and its expected output so that we can track it more easily

Comment: I just posted the question with the output that I'm looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044999/filter-in-row-of-all-columns-with-specific-conditions @akrun

Comment: @user432797 I saw that.  If we replace the `&` with `|`, i get 6944 rows out of 7270.  what is the expected number of rows